# Where do I find the version of cppunit?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cppunit

We use cppunit as our testing framework. How do I find its version over the command line (ubuntu)?
Is it listed somewhere or do I need to query the version via code?

Answer (score 1):

`cppunit-config --version`

from [here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-cppunit-config/)

> --version
>   Print the currently installed version of cppunit on the standard output.